# Convert graph to have outdegree 1 (except extra zero weight edges)

Tags: python, networkx, igraph

I am reading graphs such as http://www.dis.uniroma1.it/challenge9/data/rome/rome99.gr from http://www.dis.uniroma1.it/challenge9/download.shtml in python. For example, using this code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from igraph import *
fname = "rome99.gr"
g = Graph.Read_DIMACS(fname, directed=True )
```

(I need to change the line "p sp 3353 8870" " to "p max 3353 8870" to get this to work using igraph.)

I would like to convert the graph to one where all nodes have outdegree 1 (except for extra zero weight edges we are allowed to add) but still preserve all shortest paths.  That is a path between two nodes in the original graph should be a shortest path in the new graph if and only if it is a shortest path in the converted graph.  I will explain this a little more after an example.

One  way to do this I was thinking is to replace each node v by a little linear subgraph with v.outdegree(mode=OUT) nodes. In the subgraph the nodes are connected in sequence by zero weight edges. We then connect nodes in the subgraph to the first node in other little subgraphs we have created.

I don't mind using igraph or networkx for this task but I am stuck with the syntax of how to do it.

For example, if we start with graph G:

[image]

I would like to convert it to graph H:

[image]

As the second graph has more nodes than the first we need to define what we mean by its having the same shortest paths as the first graph.  I only consider paths between either nodes labelled with simple letters of with nodes labelled X1. In other words, in this example a path can't start or end in A2 or B2. We also merge all versions of a node when considering a path. So a path A1->A2->D in H is regarded as the same as A->D in G.

This is how far I have got.  First I add the zero weight edges to the new graph

```
h = Graph(g.ecount(), directed=True)
#Connect the nodes with zero weight edges
gtoh = [0]*g.vcount()
i=0
for v in g.vs:
    gtoh[v.index] = i 
    if (v.degree(mode=OUT) > 1):
        for j in xrange(v.degree(mode=OUT)-1):
            h.add_edge(i,i+1, weight = 0) 
            i = i+1
    i  = i + 1
```

Then I add the main edges

```
#Now connect the nodes to the relevant "head" nodes.
for v in g.vs:
    h_v_index = gtoh[v.index]
    i = 0
    for neighbour in g.neighbors(v, mode=OUT):
        h.add_edge(gtoh[v.index]+i,gtoh[neighbour], weight = g.es[g.get_eid(v.index, neighbour)]["weight"])
        i = i +1
```

Is there a nicer/better way of doing this? I feel there must be.

Comment: B1 has out-degree 2 in the second graph.

Comment: @GaborCsardi I am not counting the extra out edges we add which have 0 weight.  I added that to the question at some point, are you looking at the most current version?

Comment: what is the advantage of changing the graph in this manner? not obvious why this is even necessary.

Comment: @CorleyBrigman I need it in this format for a particular tool I am using.  It can only cope with one non-zero weight outgoing edge per node.  More generally, I would love to learn of elegant ways to do this sort of conversion just so I can get better at coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code should work in `igraph` and Python 2.x; basically it does what you proposed: it creates a "linear subgraph" for every single node in the graph, and connects exactly one outgoing edge to each node in the linear subgraph corresponding to the old node.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from igraph import Graph
from itertools import izip

def pairs(l):
    """Given a list l, returns an iterable that yields pairs of the form
    (l[i], l[i+1]) for all possible consecutive pairs of items in l"""
    return izip(l, l[1:])

def convert(g):
    # Get the old vertex names from g
    if "name" in g.vertex_attributes():
        old_names = map(str, g.vs["name"])
    else:
        old_names = map(str, xrange(g.vcount))

    # Get the outdegree vector of the old graph
    outdegs = g.outdegree()

    # Create a mapping from old node IDs to the ID of the first node in
    # the linear subgraph corresponding to the old node in the new graph
    new_node_id = 0
    old_to_new = []
    new_names = []
    for old_node_id in xrange(g.vcount()):
        old_to_new.append(new_node_id)
        new_node_id += outdegs[old_node_id]
        old_name = old_names[old_node_id]
        if outdegs[old_node_id] <= 1:
            new_names.append(old_name)
        else:
            for i in xrange(1, outdegs[old_node_id]+1):
                new_names.append(old_name + "." + str(i))

    # Add a sentinel element to old_to_new just to make our job easier
    old_to_new.append(new_node_id)

    # Create the edge list of the new graph and the weights of the new
    # edges
    new_edgelist = []
    new_weights = []

    # 1) Create the linear subgraphs
    for new_node_id, next_new_node_id in pairs(old_to_new):
        for source, target in pairs(range(new_node_id, next_new_node_id)):
            new_edgelist.append((source, target))
            new_weights.append(0)

    # 2) Create the new edges based on the old ones
    for old_node_id in xrange(g.vcount()):
        new_node_id = old_to_new[old_node_id]
        for edge_id in g.incident(old_node_id, mode="out"):
            neighbor = g.es[edge_id].target
            new_edgelist.append((new_node_id, old_to_new[neighbor]))
            new_node_id += 1
            print g.es[edge_id].source, g.es[edge_id].target, g.es[edge_id]["weight"]
            new_weights.append(g.es[edge_id]["weight"])

    # Return the graph
    vertex_attrs = {"name": new_names}
    edge_attrs = {"weight": new_weights}
    return Graph(new_edgelist, directed=True, vertex_attrs=vertex_attrs, \
            edge_attrs=edge_attrs)
```